# mySQL Query select / join not working as expected

Tags: mysql

let me preface that I've done a good bit of searching to see if this issue can be resolved but have yet to find an answer that relates, so I'll ask now.  I have a query that works (mostly) to pull from two separate tables to show a total amount of pc models in each of four locations(these locations are in a single column, so I'm trying to select them as their own columns through aliases).  The query pulls all required info, but not as I was hoping it would.

Expectation:

```
model | loc1 | loc2 | loc3 | loc4
5530  | 3    | 2    | 1    | 0
6440  | 10   | 0    | 3    | 20
```

Reality:

```
model | loc1 | loc2 | loc3 | loc4
5530  | 3    | null | null | null
5530  | null | 2    | null | null
5530  | null | null | 1    | null
```

etc..

Here is my query, any help to make the reality match the expectation if possible would be appreciated.

```
SELECT 
      a.model,
      (select COUNT(a.model)
             WHERE a.location = 'AoC-Reno') AS Reno,
      (select count(a.model)
             where a.location = 'AoC-Fargo') AS Fargo,
      (select count(a.model)
              where a.location = 'EoC') AS EoC,
      (select count(a.model)
              where a.location = 'APoC') as APoC
FROM assets AS a
join models m on m.model = a.model  
WHERE m.type IN ('Desktop','Laptop')
AND a.model = m.model
AND a.status != 'Recycled'
GROUP BY m.model, a.location
ORDER BY m.model
```

Comment: Remove a.location from group by clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT a.model,
       SUM(a.location = 'AoC-Reno') AS Reno,
       SUM(a.location = 'AoC-Fargo') AS Fargo,
       SUM(a.location = 'EoC') AS EoC,
       SUM(a.location = 'APoC') as APoC
FROM models m JOIN
     assets a
     on m.model = a.model  
WHERE m.type IN ('Desktop', 'Laptop') and a.status <> 'Recycled'
GROUP BY m.model
ORDER BY m.model;
```

Your query has multiple issues:

- You are using a "subquery", but there is no `FROM` clause.
- You are aggregating by both `model` and `location`, but you want only one row per `model`.
- The `JOIN` condition is both in the `ON` clause and repeated in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, this has solved my issue and the explanation makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a conditional aggregation (count)

```sql
SELECT a.model,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.location = 'AoC-Reno' THEN 1 END)  reno,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.location = 'AoC-Fargo' THEN 1 END)  farggo,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.location = 'EoC' THEN 1 END)  eoc,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.location = 'APoC' THEN 1 END)  apoc
  FROM assets AS a JOIN models m 
    ON m.model = a.model  
 WHERE m.type IN ('Desktop','Laptop')
   AND a.status != 'Recycled'
GROUP BY m.model
ORDER BY m.model
```